# Backbone template method. Why are we passing in a model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I can't figure out why we are passing in a model.toJSON() into this template:

```
app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this; // enable chained calls
  }
});
```

The example comes from this [tutorial](http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2012/09/13/backbone-js-for-absolute-beginners-getting-started-part-2/).

`this.template(this.model.toJSON())` is the confusing part to me. The template method doesn't seem to take in an argument right? What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Underscore `_.template` function](http://underscorejs.org/#template) takes a template string as argument (and optionally a settings object) and returns a new pre-compiled template function which takes an object as an argument.

This object is the data used within the template:

```
// creates a template function
var templateFunc = _.template("<span><%= name %></span>");

// render the template using the passed data
templateFunc({ name: "Émile" }); // <span>Émile</span>
```

> By default, `template` places the values from your data in the local
>   scope via the `with` statement. However, you can specify a single
>   variable name with the `variable` setting.
>
> ```
> _.template("Using 'with': <%= data.answer %>", {variable: 'data'})({answer: 'no'});
> ```

[`model.toJSON()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) returns a shallow copy or the `attributes` hash of the model.

To achieve the equivalent of the above example:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({ name: "Émile" });
templateFunc(model.toJSON()); // <span>Émile</span>
```

---

For [Underscore.js before v1.7](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/underscore/1.6.0/index.html#template), the template function signature was a little different:

```
_.template(templateString, [data], [settings])
```

If a data object was passed, it didn't returned a function, but returned the rendered template string directly.

```
_.template('This is <%= val %>.', { val: "deprecated" });
// This is deprecated.
```

Comment: Oh I see. `_.template($('#item-template').html())` returns a function: `function (a){return e.call(this,a,b)}`

Comment: @Jwan622 exactly, it looks confusing sometimes because Backbone views have a `template` property which we usually fill with the return value of `_.template`.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Thanks!