# Backbone event click on table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I created a view for table row, that i want to listen to any click on any cells in this row.
This is how I implemented:

```
let ListItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click tr': 'showDetails',
        'click': 'showDetails'
    },
    template: function() {
        return "<tr><td><img src=<%= imageUrl %> /></td><td class='name'><%= firstName %></td><td><%= lastName %></td><td><%= homeTown %></td><td><button type='button' id='ddd' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
    },
    render: function() {
        var oTemplate = _.template(this.template());
        this.$el.html(oTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
        $('table > tbody:last-child').append(this.$el.html());
        return this;
    },
    showDetails: function() {
        alert("*****");
    },
    hide: function(bToHide, index) {
        index++;
        if (!bToHide) {
            $($('tr')[index]).show();
            return;
        }
        $($('tr')[index]).hide();
        this.rendered = true;
    },
    openActorView: function() {
        window.open('/#actor/' + window.actorsCollection.indexOf(this.model), '_self');
    }
});
```

After clicking the row\cells within, nothing happens.
I listen to click on this view + click on the tr, but nothing happens.

Also, when add event to `tr td` nothing happens ether.

Thanks for helping

Comment: I think that the enclosing tag in a template is replaced by the view element, so if you check the DOM most likely you won't find `<tr>` there. Try specifying the view element as `tr` and it won't hurt either if you set your event hash as `'click td':...`

Comment: @vassiliskrikonis there is for each row a tr element

Comment: did you change to `click td` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The reason it doesn't work

```
$('table > tbody:last-child').append(this.$el.html());
```

The [jQuery `.html()` function returns a string](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

So you're creating a nice Backbone view, with easy to define event listeners, then you don't use it, you just take its string representation and dump it in the DOM, **losing any event listeners previously bound.**

## The improvements

First, there's no need to make the template a function, just use `_.template` directly. I wrote another answer which provides additional information on [how to use `_.template`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148034/1218980).

After that, **don't use global selectors inside a view.** It kills the purpose of a scoped component view. Let the parent view class deals with this.

```
let ListItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr', // the list item is a `<tr>`
    events: {
        'click': 'showDetails'
    },
    template: _.template("<td><img src=<%= imageUrl %> /></td><td class='name'><%= firstName %></td><td><%= lastName %></td><td><%= homeTown %></td><td><button type='button' id='ddd' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></td>"),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    showDetails: function() {
        console.log("show details event");
    }
});
```

Make a list view that manages the table. This is the parent class that will put the list items into the DOM.

Instead of using the jQuery core function, use the [Backbone view scoped alias `this.$()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321584/1218980) to cache the table body.

```
let ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.$body = this.$('tbody');
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$body.empty();
        this.collection.each(this.renderItem, this);
        return this;
    },
    renderItem: function(model) {
        var view = new ListItem({ model: model });
        this.$body.append(view.render().el); // use the DOMElement
    }
});
```

Then pass an existing table from outside the view.

```
new ListView({ el: 'table.my-table' }).render();
```

---

This is a super basic example and you should be aware that performance could be improved further and that it could leak memory if used as-is.

See how to [improve list rendering performance with Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44034868/1218980).